# Is there any difference between lists partition and splitwith in Erlang?

Tags: list, data-structures, functional-programming, erlang

Like in the title. Both, [`lists:partition/2`](http://erlang.org/documentation/doc-5.9.3/lib/stdlib-1.18.3/doc/html/lists.html#partition-2) and [`lists:splitwith/2`](http://erlang.org/documentation/doc-5.9.3/lib/stdlib-1.18.3/doc/html/lists.html#splitwith-2) take the function predicate and a list as input and produce a tuple with two lists, one for which the predicate returns `true` and the other one for which the predicate returns `false`.

What confuses me is the last sentence:

> See also (here is the other function) for a different way to partition a list.

Surely they would write that both functions partition the list in the same way rather than different way if they were to be giving the same result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your question - yes, there is difference between those functions. And now to the explanation:

As written in the documentation for `lists:splitwith/2`

> Partitions `List` into two lists according to `Pred`. `splitwith/2` behaves
>   as if it is defined as follows:
>
> `splitwith(Pred, List) ->
>       {takewhile(Pred, List), dropwhile(Pred, List)}.`

This means that `Pred(Elem)` runs on elements from `List` starting from its first element. **While** `Pred(Elem)` returns `true`, `Elem` will be added to the first list. **Once** we get to an element that `Pred(Elem)` returns `false`, the rest of the elements in `List` will go to the second list.

In contrast, `lists:partition/2` runs `Pred(Elem)` on **all** elements of `List`. If it returns `true` for a specific element it will go to the first list, and if it returns `false` that element will go to the second list. It won't 'stop' on the first element that returns `false` such as in `lists:splitwith/2`.

Lets take a look at another simple example other than the two that are given in the  documentation:

```
1> List = [a,b,a,b].
[a,b,a,b]
2> Pred = fun(Elem) -> Elem =:= a end.
#Fun<erl_eval.6.54118792>
3> lists:partition(Pred,List).
{[a,a],[b,b]}
4> lists:splitwith(Pred,List).
{[a],[b,a,b]}
```

As we can see, our `Pred` function returns `true` when `Elem =:= a`.

In case we run `lists:partition/2` it will go over **all** the elements. So we get all the elements from `List` that are equal to `a` on the first list of the returned tuple, and the rest on the second list.

In case we run `lists:splitwith/2` the iteration 'stops' when it gets to the first element where `Pred(Elem)` returns `false`. In this case it stops on the second element `b` and all the elements from this one till the end of the list goes to the second list of the returned tuple.

Comment: Oh, right, of course. Now I remember that I was looking into that before and I came to the same conclusion, and then I have forgotten again. Thanks for the comprehensive explanation! In that sense `splitwith` is a more intelligent version of `split/2` which simply takes a specified amount of elements into the first list and then the rest into the second list.

Answer (score 3):

I think the source code is very clear.

```
partition(Pred, L) ->
    partition(Pred, L, [], []).

partition(Pred, [H | T], As, Bs) ->
    case Pred(H) of
    true -> partition(Pred, T, [H | As], Bs);
    false -> partition(Pred, T, As, [H | Bs])
    end;
partition(Pred, [], As, Bs) when is_function(Pred, 1) ->
    {reverse(As), reverse(Bs)}.
```

splitwith/2:

```
splitwith(Pred, List) when is_function(Pred, 1) ->
    splitwith(Pred, List, []).

splitwith(Pred, [Hd|Tail], Taken) ->
    case Pred(Hd) of
    true -> splitwith(Pred, Tail, [Hd|Taken]);
    false -> {reverse(Taken), [Hd|Tail]}
    end;
splitwith(Pred, [], Taken) when is_function(Pred, 1) ->
    {reverse(Taken),[]}.
```

You can see `splitwith/2` will end the recursion when `Pred` is false.